# IB API - 'App' object has no attribute 'nextValidOderId'

Tags: python, class, ib-api

I am a newbie and confused with the nextOrderId.
In the testing code I have the following:

```
order_id = self.nextValidOrderId
print('order_id', order_id)
next_order_id = self.nextOrderId()
print('next_order_id', next_order_id)
```

But the response puzzles me:

```
order_id 1
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
    140 order_id = self.nextValidOrderId
    141 print('order_id', order_id)
--> 142 next_order_id = self.nextOrderId()
    143 print('next_order_id', next_order_id)
...
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'nextValidOderId'
```

In the class I have the standard "def nextValidId" and "def nextOrderId":

> ```
> def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
>     super().nextValidId(orderId)
>     self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
>     print("NextValidOrderId: ", orderId)
>     self.start()
>
> def nextOrderId(self):
>     oid = self.nextValidOrderId
>     self.nextValidOderId += 1
>     return oid
> ```

How is the self.nextValidOrderId became "lost"?

Thank you very much for you help in advance.

Comment: `nextValidOderId` and `nextValidOrderId` are different words. (besides naming convention violation)

Comment: That's it! Probably I am working too much so I missed the typo. Thank you very much.